# Prove $\frac{pq}{(p-1)(q-1)} < 2$ for distinct odd primes $p,q$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory

I need this lemma for another proof I'm doing, but I can't crack it. I want something of the structure:

$$\frac{pq}{(p-1)(q-1)} < \dots = \frac{pq}{\frac{1}{2}pq} = 2,$$ 
but I can't figure out what to do with the denominator.

Comment: It may be easier to work with the reciprocal
$$\frac{(p-1)(q-1)}{pq}=(1-\frac1p)(1-\frac1q)\ge????$$

Answer (score 3):

As $p\geq3$, $q\geq5$, we have $p/(p-1)\leq3/2$, $q/(q-1)\leq5/4$.

Comment: Is more justification needed to show $p/(p-1)\leq 3/2$? Intuitively this can be seen (as the limit as $p$ goes to infinity of $p / (p-1)$ goes to $1$ and the sequence monotonically decreasing, to be super pedantic)

Comment: @user3724404 It is $\left(1+\dfrac{1}{p-1}\right)$, which is strongly decreasing for $p>1$.

Comment: @user3724404 Not need at all of intuition, monotony or limits: $$\frac p{p-1}\le\frac32\iff2p\le3p-3\iff p\ge 3...\text{and this last is given}\;$$ , and like wise with the other fraction.

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{pq}{(p-1)(q-1)} <2\Longleftrightarrow pq-2p-2q+2 =(p-2)(q-2)-2>0$$
for $p\ge 3$ and $q\ge 4$.

Answer (score 0):

You could prove that $1<\frac{k}{k-1} < \frac{\ell}{\ell-1}$ for $k>\ell$ and then observe that $\frac {3\times 5}{2\times4}<2$, and that choosing larger odd primes will thus make the result smaller.

Answer (score 0):

Assume $p>q$:
$$
2(p-1)(q-1)-pq=pq-2p-2q+2>pq-4p+2=p(q-4)+2
$$
which is $>0$ for $q>3$. For $q=3$,
$$
2(p-1)(q-1)-pq=4(p-1)-3p=p-4>0
$$
Therefore $2(p-1)(q-1)>pq$.

Answer (score 0):

If $p\le q$ are odd primes, then $p=3+a$ and $q=5+b$ for some $a,b\ge0$.  We have

$$\begin{align}
{pq\over(p-1)(q-1)}={(3+a)(5+b)\over(2+a)(4+b)}\lt2
&\iff15+5a+3b+ab\lt2(8+4a+2b+ab)\\
&\iff0\lt1+3a+b+ab
\end{align}$$

The inequality has very little to do with $p$ and $q$ being either distinct, odd, or prime.